# foreach and if, displaying content in correct order

Tags: php

Here is my code, it basically grabs `$banners` and displays them out, there are 2 at the moment, however , it stops after the first one and displays out the html `div id="footerNews...` etc and carries on again after that. This is correct...

```
    <?php if ($banners) { $i = 1; ?>
<div id="footerBanners">
    <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a> 

        <?php if ($i == 1) { ?>
            <div id="footerNewsletter">
                <p>Newsletter Sign Up</p>
                <a href="#">Go</a>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
            </div>
            <div id="footerEvents"><a href="<?php echo $events; ?>"><?php echo $text_events; ?></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that some of variables in `$banners` dont actually have a link. To get around this, I attempted to put an `if` statement in to not display `<a href>` if there is no link. however this messes up the order that of the content, its important that I keep the content in the correct order as above ^. Here was my attempt.

```
    <?php if ($banners) { $i = 1; ?>
<div id="footerBanners">
    <?php foreach ($banners as $banner) { ?>
        <?php if ($banner['link'] == '') { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /><?php } 
        else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $banner['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $banner['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $banner['title']; ?>" /></a><?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($i == 1) { ?>
            <div id="footerNewsletter">
                <p>Newsletter Sign Up</p>
                <a href="#">Go</a>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
            </div>
            <div id="footerEvents"><a href="<?php echo $events; ?>"><?php echo $text_events; ?></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
</div>
```

While the code does what it says its supposed to do, its not displaying the correct order anymore, its displaying the 1 linkable `$banner` then the html, and THEN the image(ie the second `$banner` with no link. However I need it to display in the same layout as the first bit of code.
Here is the outputted html code, although the image is appearing last on the site.

```
        <div id="footerBanners">
                            <img src="http://mysite.com/image/data/banner4.jpg" alt="Free Delivery" />                          
                            <a href="http://mysite.com/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path=500_509"><img src="http://mysite.com/image/data/banner5.jpg" alt="Gift Vouchers" /></a>                                        <div id="footerNewsletter">
                <p>Newsletter Sign Up</p>
                <a href="#">Go</a>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
            </div>
            <div id="footerEvents"><a href="http://mysite.com/index.php?route=information/information&amp;information_id=17">EVENTS</a></div>
                    </div>
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Please post a sample of the HTML source that this outputs. It looks to me like it should be in the correct order. Is it perhaps your CSS which is changing the positions of the banner image if not wrapped in `<a>`?

Comment: $i++ line is messing, because you have if($i == 1){html codes here } but $i++ is increasing value of $i to 2 and if block will be skipped anymore. I think you should fix this part.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if you are going to use php this way. You can also use `<?php if ( $i == 1 ): ?> .... <?php endif; ?>` Much more readable then having `<?php } ?>` entries in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ($banners) { 
 echo '<div id="footerBanners">';

 foreach ($banners as $banner) {
    if ($banner['link'] == '') { 
        echo '<img src="'.$banner['image'].'" alt="'.$banner['title'].'" />'; 
    }
    else { 
        echo '<a href="'.$banner['link'].'"><img src="'.$banner['image'].'" alt="'.$banner['title'].'" /></a>';
    }
    if ($first_banner != 'displayed') { 

        echo '<div id="footerNewsletter">
                    <p>Newsletter Sign Up</p>
                    <a href="#">Go</a>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
                </div>
                <div id="footerEvents"><a href="'.$events.'">'.$text_events.'</a></div>';
        $first_banner = 'displayed';
    }
 }
 echo '</div>';    
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes this is better - there was an extra `}` which mistakenly closed the foreach loop early

Comment: thanks, but Im starting to think its a CSS issue, your code worked , but it did the same thing as mine and the image is now at the end again. Very strange

Comment: When I remove the `<a>` tag from the first line of code, the image goes to the end again. Thanks for the help, Ill give this as the answer when I can be sure its the CSS.

Comment: found the problem, my other elements were floating left.